# how to perform string formatting inside a dictionary?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

lets say i have a payload which i am using to hit my API

```
payload = json.dumps({"from_date":"2019-10-10",
                      "from_date":"2019-10-12",
                     "pg_no": 1,
                     "idx": "fsdf"})
```

but i wanted to make its `pg_no` value as dynamic using for loop i.e.

```
payload = json.dumps({"from_date":"2019-10-10",
                          "from_date":"2019-10-12",
                         "pg_no": {},
                         "idx": "fsdf"})

for i in range(1,5):
   payload.format(i)
```

getting this error

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-5b565a97da5e> in <module>
      1 for i in range(1,5):
----> 2        payload.format(i)

KeyError: '"from_date"'
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: You are looking for `'{}'` not `{}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first in your dictionary you are using same key `from_data` which is gonna be only last one present there.
second main problem is causing by `{` bracket `format` use this place variable  if you want to parse single single `{` then you have to use `{{`  in string
. so simple put value in dictionary then convert to string like this

```
data = {'rom_date':'2019-10-10',
        'fom_date':'2019-10-12',
                     'pg_no': {},
                     'idx': 'fsdf'}

for i in range(1,5):
    data['pg_no'] = i 
    print(json.dumps(data))
```